# php - ldap search is taking almost 30-35 seconds to search

Tags: php, ldap

I am using ldap search to get users infomation by userid. There are total 500 records and a function to get user's info from LDAP is being called 500 times.

```
inside while loop
$userInfo = getUserInfo($booking_info['user_id']);
```

And below is the getUserInfo function.

```
function getUserInfo($passedUserId){
    global $ldapConnection;
    global $bind;
    global $baseDn;
    if($bind){
        $ldapFilter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $passedUserId . ")";
        $ldapResult = ldap_search($ldapConnection, $baseDn, $ldapFilter);
        $ldapInfo   = ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $ldapResult);
        if(isset($ldapInfo[0])){
            if($ldapInfo[0]["givenname"][0]){
                $firstName      = $ldapInfo[0]["givenname"][0];
            }
            if($ldapInfo[0]["sn"][0]){
                $lastName       = $ldapInfo[0]["sn"][0];
            }
            if($ldapInfo[0]["mail"][0]){
                $emailAddress   = $ldapInfo[0]["mail"][0];
            }
            if ($ldapInfo[0]["extensionattribute1"][0]) {
                $costCentre = $ldapInfo[0]["extensionattribute1"][0];
            }
            if ($ldapInfo[0]["department"][0]) {
                $organizationalUnit = $ldapInfo[0]["department"][0];
            }
            if ($ldapInfo[0]["manager"][0]) {
                $lineManager = split("=", split(",", $ldapInfo[0]["manager"][0])[0])[1];
            }
            return Array($firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress, $costCentre, $organizationalUnit, $lineManager);
        }
    }
    return Array('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None');
}
```

This takes approximately 30-35 seconds to finish the request.

**How do I optimize this function to speed up the search ?**

Comment: hard to say where the bottle neck might be... can you replace everything in your `getUserInfo` function with somthing simple like `return true;` and run it again and see if that is causing that slow response time.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Yes I did and found out that `ldap_search` is making it slow. So, how can I make built-in function to work fast ?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the getUserInfo function to accept an array of user_ids and ldap_search filter has a feature to pass multiple ids in a single request.

Passing array of 500 user_ids, so only once call to getMultipleUserInfo.

The filterString will be "(|(sAMAccountName=user_id0)(sAMAccountName=user_id1)(sAMAccountName=user_id2).....(sAMAccountName=user_id499))"

```
function getMultipleUserInfo($passedUsersArray){
    global $ldapConnection;
    global $bind;
    global $baseDn;
    $userInfoArray = Array();
    $filterString = '';
    $count = 0;
    if(is_array($passedUsersArray)){
        foreach ($passedUsersArrayas $key => $value) {
            $count++;
            $filterString .= "(sAMAccountName=" . $key . ")";                
        }
    }
    if($bind){
        $ldapFilter = "(|" . $filterString . ")";
        $justthese  = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail");
        $ldapResult = ldap_search($ldapConnection, $baseDn, $ldapFilter, Array(), 0, 0);
        $ldapInfo   = ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $ldapResult);
        for($info=0; $info<count($ldapInfo); $info++){
            if(isset($ldapInfo[$info])){
                if($ldapInfo[$info]["givenname"][0]){
                    $firstName      = $ldapInfo[$info]["givenname"][0];
                }
                if($ldapInfo[$info]["sn"][0]){
                    $lastName       = $ldapInfo[$info]["sn"][0];
                }
                if($ldapInfo[$info]["mail"][0]){
                    $emailAddress   = $ldapInfo[$info]["mail"][0];
                }
                if ($ldapInfo[$info]["extensionattribute1"][0]) {
                    $costCentre = $ldapInfo[$info]["extensionattribute1"][0];
                }
                if ($ldapInfo[$info]["department"][0]) {
                    $organizationalUnit = $ldapInfo[$info]["department"][0];
                }
                if ($ldapInfo[$info]["manager"][0]) {
                    $lineManager = split("=", split(",", $ldapInfo[$info]["manager"][0])[0])[1];
                }
                if ($ldapInfo[$info]["extensionattribute7"][0]) {
                    $usr= strtolower($ldapInfo[$info]["extensionattribute7"][0]);
                }
                // return Array($firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress, $costCentre, $organizationalUnit, $lineManager);
                if($usr=== ''){
                    $usr= 'invalid';
                }
                $userInfoArray [$usr] = Array($firstName, $lastName, $emailAddress, $costCentre, $organizationalUnit, $lineManager);
            }
        }
        return $userInfoArray ;
    }
    return Array('None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None');
}
```

This now takes 3-4 seconds to finish the search.